# How do I insert the current visual selection phrase into the command-line?

Tags: vim

When entering an argument on the command, I know I can type `<C-R><C-W>` to insert the word under the cursor and `<C-R><C-A>` to insert the WORD under the cursor.

Is there a way to insert the current visual-selection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the contents of any register on the ex or search command-lines with `<C-R>` followed by the register's name. By yanking your visual selection, it is put into the `0` register, so `<C-R>0` will add your yanked selection to the current command-line.

That is the only way I know of, but I still use it on a daily basis.

Comment: So simple...thanks!  I mostly composed my own answer because I was curious myself

Comment: What if i didn't yank it yet?

Comment: @minseong If you want to run the same command on a bunch of selections, you can make a `vnoremap` or macro to yank-paste-run

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways your question can be construed.  The easiest is if you mean you want to give the selected text as a range argument to an ex command.  I doubt this is your question, since this happens automatically if you type : with a visual selection, but the ex syntax for this

```
:'<,'>
```

The second way I think your question could be construed is that you want to insert the visual selected text itself as an argument to an ex command; I don't think this can be done.  If you read the vim manual section [40.2](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.2), where range arguments are described, the only things that a command is allowed to grab from a range argument is the number of the first line and the last line (using the tags `<line1>` and `<line2>`).

Finally, if you want to *run* the selected text on the *shell* command line, all you need to do is select it and type

```
:!sh
```

(The `'<,'>` part should get inserted for you between the : and the !.  You can replace 'sh' with the command to start your favorite shell).

Comment: Hi David, the second of the three ways you describe was indeed my intention. i.e., a inserted the visually selected object into the command-line, in the same way that <C-R><C-W> inserts the word object.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the register `*` contains the current visual selection...

You can type `<C-R>*` to get it from insert or command mode...

However, this is not very handy to use it in a command line, since you can't avoid the  `'<,'>` when entering command mode from visual mode

Comment: No, register `*` does not necessarily contain the current visual selection. In general the register `*` contains the X11 selection, which can be totally different. Secondly, you can use `<c-u>` to clear the command line (and remove the `'<, '>`)